# small database installable through npm and supporting multi-process and cluster

Tags: node.js

I am distributing a module through npm, and it needs a little database to persist some data. I would like this to be self-contained, and that the users wouldn't have to setup their own database on the side. I am currently using [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) which did the trick so far, except that now I want to use clusters in my library which means that *nedb* is not going to work anymore. I had a look into other similar solutions (like [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb)), but none of them fits the bill, cause they don't support concurrency ... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one! It is implemented in node and supports concurrency https://github.com/realm/realm-js